# Qual è il significato di "masticava un americano indecente" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Vita lo aggiornava sui repentini cambi di impiego di Nicola: fino a settembre era uno dei facchini addetti ai bagagli dei clienti dell’hotel Ansonia – per questo era riuscito a raccomandarla all’addetto alle griglie per un posto nelle cucine. Purtroppo Coca-cola era sbadato, confondeva i numeri sulle porte, **masticava un americano indecente** che faceva inorridire i clienti, si innamorava delle cameriere dei piani, che inseguiva abbandonando le valigie negli ascensori.

Dovete sapere che "Coca-cola" è un soprannome con cui viene chiamato Nicola. Ho cercato il termine "americano" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione che corrisponda a qualcosa che si possa masticare. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Un piccolo suggerimento, @Charo: forse potrebbe essere utile aggiungere, nella domanda, l’aggettivo “indecente”, che completa il complemento oggetto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In questo contesto, sta parlando della lingua, ovvero significa che il personaggio parlava e capiva l'inglese (americano) poco e male.

L'espressione colloquiale *"masticare una lingua"* per indicare la propria dimestichezza con la stessa è di uso comune; si utilizza anche in senso più ampio per indicare la padronanza riguardo qualunque argomento, ad es.

> Non mastico di politica

Oppure:

> Quanto ne mastichi di informatica?

Answer (score 1):

Per completare la risposta di @RiccardoDeContardi aggiungo l’accezione di *[masticare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/masticare/)* che si adatta al contesto da te citato, fonte Treccani:

> **2b**. In usi fam. e scherz.: **m. bene (o male) una lingua, essere capace di esprimersi in essa più o meno bene;** quindi: *m. un po’ di
>   russo; d’inglese ne mastica poco*.